# It is possible to quickly align an object with an axis of a custom transformation?

Tags: interface, transform-orientation

After creating a cube in the global orientation, is it possible to quickly align it with an axis of a custom frame of reference?

Use: Align [rafters](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-4141952b0a22542840d02ddb3e4efad9) with the roof slope for which a custom orientation has been defined:

[image]

<sup>Simple 'cube' which longitudinal axis should be aligned with Z of the Roof frame of reference</sup>

Comment: have you tried to snap the second object? with Face option and all other options enabled, and its origin on one of its faces

Comment: I gave you a trick that could work (snap tool), maybe this video could also answer your question (don't know): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0pfTDzAaXp4

Comment: I prefer your solution to the one in the video, there is no hook to create and then remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell me if this is what you want:

- Create you first object and rotate it.
- Create your second object, put its origine on its base (with *Cursor to Selected* then *Origin to Cursor*).
- Activate the *Snap* tool of your horizontal menu bar, choose *Face* mode, enable all options.
- Grab your second object, it will snap on the surface of the first one.
- You can assign an Array modifier to your object so that it duplicates along.

[image]

Comment: Ah yes, this is a great tip! The second option (Project individual elements on the surface of other objects') mustn't be activated for a source face to snap on a target face.